# Can I make my smoke look white like snow?

Tags: fluid-simulation, smoke-simulation

I have a smoke simulation and I want to make it look white like snow but, even when I turn the color to pure white, it looks dark like smoke (using the "Principled Volume" shader). **Is there a method to shade the smoke sim to color it white like snow?**

Answer (score 0):

I found this node setup from Blender Made Easy's [tutorial](https://youtu.be/NxtztAKyPU0?t=290). The "Light Path" node is only there to make sure that, since the smoke is technically now emitting light, it won't effect the scene (only needed for cycles). The bottom "value" on the second multiply node (circled in green) controls how white it is. For all of the other info on what does what, check out the tutorial.